# copy content from popup

Tags: popup, openlayers-3

How to achieve opportunity copy content from popup-open?

[In OpenLayers-2 I could select part of content popup and copy it.](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/getfeatureinfo-popup.html)

In OL-3 miss this option.

[Popup-open has disable default option select content from popup.](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/popup.html?q=popup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is related to this issue: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/6720

However I think setting `user-select: auto` for the `.ol-selectable` class doesn't have the desired effect as according to [the spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui-4/#valdef-user-select-auto) the value of  `auto` will results in  `none` if the computed value of `user-select` on the parent of this element is `none`, which it is in OpenLayers due to `user-select` being set on the `.ol-viewport`.

Try adding this CSS to your page after the OpenLayers CSS is loaded:

```
.ol-selectable {
    -webkit-touch-callout: text;
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    -moz-user-select: text;
    -ms-user-select: text;
    user-select: text;
}
```

Comment: I've just created a pull request which should address the issue: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/8030

Comment: Sorry, at me this solution doesn't work. Changed ol.css library ol v 4.6.4  and without luck. Anyway thanks for reply and pull request to OpenLayers.

Comment: Doesn't work in popup-open. But works in popup-hover... strange.

Comment: Everything works proper. I have ol-ext library with ol-selectable { ...:none }  Many thanks!